# Looping through an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
@candidates = [
  {
    id: 15,
    years_of_experience: 4,
    github_points: 293,
    languages: ['C', 'Ruby', 'Python', 'Clojure'],
    age: 26
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    years_of_experience: 1,
    github_points: 145,
    languages: ['JavaScript', 'Ruby', 'Go', 'Erlang'],
    age: 19
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    years_of_experience: 6,
    github_points: 435,
    languages: ['JavaScript', 'SQL', 'C#'],    age: 32
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    years_of_experience: 3,
    github_points: 232,
    languages: ['Java', 'Ruby', 'JavaScript'],
    age: 31
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    years_of_experience: 12,
    github_points: 32,
    languages: ['VB', 'Cobol', 'Fortran'],
    age: 42
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    years_of_experience: 2,
    github_points: 328,
    languages: ['Python', 'Ruby', 'JavaScript'],
    age: 25
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    years_of_experience: 1,
    github_points: 400,
    languages: ['JavaScript', 'Ruby'],
    age: 16
  },
]
```

I am trying to take an argument `id` and return a hash within `@candidates` whose value for `:id` matches `id`. If no match is found, it returns `nil`.

My method looks like this:

```
def find(id)
  for candidate in @candidates
    if candidate[:id] == id
      return candidate
    else
      return nil
    end
  end
end

find(15)
```

This however returns `nil` as soon as it finishes with the first item in the array. It should continue to the end of the array and find all matches, and if it finds none, return `nil`, not simply return `nil` for the first instance it doesn't find a match.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not set it up as a hash of hashes rather than an array of hashes, where each hash is accessed by the id?  You would avoid the need to loop and get your result in constant time.  Also, since you're looking things up by id, you clearly don't need to store it inside the hash so you're free to make it the index without having redundancy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the problem is that you are returning too early, then you can simply refrain from returning early.  This should work:

```
def find(id)
  for candidate in @candidates
    if candidate[:id] == id
      return candidate 
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

But a nicer way to do it would be:

```
def find(id)
  @candidates.find { |c| c[:id] == id }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running many such "find one" calls it's better performance to index the list by transforming it to a hash:

```
indexed_candidates = candidates.index_by { |obj| obj[:id] }

def find(id)
  indexed_candidates[id]
end
```

This is O(1) time to call `find`, versus O(N) to loop through it each time.

However this depends on the candidates list being static, if you need to add / remove you would need to rebuild or update the index.

**EDIT**

Since it was pointed out that `index_by` is not in ruby core (you just have to `require 'active_support/all`, though) if you are using ruby 2.4 or newer you can use `transform_values`:

```
indexed_candidates = candidates
  .group_by { |obj| obj[:id] }
  .transform_values(&:first)
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by David Grayson, the direct answer is you're returning too early.

A potentially better solution is to use a hash of hashes rather than an array of hashes, based on the `id` as the key.  This would be far more efficient than a loop-based search for lookup, and would also force you to confront the fact that you have duplicate `id`s in your data.

```
@candidates = {
  15 => {
    years_of_experience: 4,
    github_points: 293,
    languages: ['C', 'Ruby', 'Python', 'Clojure'],
    age: 26
  },
  7 => {
    years_of_experience: 1,
    github_points: 145,
    languages: ['JavaScript', 'Ruby', 'Go', 'Erlang'],
    age: 19
  },
  9 => {
    years_of_experience: 6,
    github_points: 435,
    languages: ['JavaScript', 'SQL', 'C#'],    age: 32
  },
  11 => {
    id: 11,
    years_of_experience: 3,
    github_points: 232,
    languages: ['Java', 'Ruby', 'JavaScript'],
    age: 31
  },
  '11a' => { # note that you have two 11's! 
    years_of_experience: 12,
    github_points: 32,
    languages: ['VB', 'Cobol', 'Fortran'],
    age: 42
  },
  13 => {
    years_of_experience: 2,
    github_points: 328,
    languages: ['Python', 'Ruby', 'JavaScript'],
    age: 25
  },
  '15a' => { # ditto for 15's
    years_of_experience: 1,
    github_points: 400,
    languages: ['JavaScript', 'Ruby'],
    age: 16
  },
}

p @candidates[15] # => {:years_of_experience=>4, :github_points=>293, :languages=>["C", "Ruby", "Python", "Clojure"], :age=>26}
p @candidates[42] # => nil
```

Note that you don't need a `find` method, it's just a normal hash access.  Also note that this returns `nil` if a matching `id` is not found, as desired.

Comment: you can do this with the `index_by` method as i show in my answer.

Comment: @maxpleaner Not in plain Ruby.  `index_by` is a rails method.

Comment: You're right, I thought one of the newer Rubies has added it but I was thinking of transform_keys/transform_values.

Comment: Interestingly, `group_by` is in ruby core, so you could do `.group_by { |obj| obj[:id] }.transform_values(&:first)`  since 2.4